# HTML5 datetime-local. How to accept Y-m-d only

Tags: jquery, html, forms, datetime

I'm building a form with a datetime-local input.

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" />
```

When I'm clicking on the today-button the date sets to today like this

**2018-11-05 --:--**

When I post the form, the datetime field is empty because the hours and minutes isn't set. When setting hours and minutes to eg. 00:00 it works.

Could I somehow automatically set the hours and minutes to 00:00 when it's not defined?

Comment: The date you posted is in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` format, do you want a different format or is this just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the the time(09:32) the i would use the type="date".

```
<input type="date">
```

The datetime-local is a bad type because it not supported by firefox!

But if you want to use datetime you could run this on load

```
document.getElementById("datetime").value = "2018-11-05T00:00";
```

This will set the time to 00:00 when the user click the "today" button the time will stay at 00:00

Comment: That wasn't even the question. OP still wants to display time but setting it to 00:00 when it's not defined by the user.